# How to call wizard in create method in odoo-11?

Tags: python-2.7, wizard, odoo-11

I need to call a wizard from Create method, I searched a lot on the web and I found that is impossible to achieve that.  My purpose is to check if a condition is true or not before creating a new record and if this condition is true a wizard will be called. Otherwise, the record will be created normally.

The pseudo-code is like below :

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals)
if condition:
    return wizard
else:
   return super(model_name, self).create(vals)
```

Any help, please ?